# How to prevent jQuery-UI moved + resized images from taking more space?

Tags: jquery-ui, html, image-resizing

I have a bunch of images on the page, that I use jQuery-UI to allow moving around and resizing. It looks great, with one major side effect: whenever a moved image is resized, it's original location is resized as well, pushing the other images out of place.

I understand the logic behind it (from the document's POV, the image is still in its original location), but is there a way to prevent this visually-disturbing behavior? Possibly a jQuery-UI option I've missed? Or a way to restrict the original space from growing/shrinking?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess there are no answers here. Will attempt to clone the images and leave an original at its place. Will be a hassle to manage, but I still don't see a simple solution.